# Cut and Paste from Edge to Outlook Loses Formatting

Tags: outlook, formatting, microsoft-edge, cut-and-paste

At my job we have an internal web application which creates some formatted text which is inserted into an email.  My preferred browser for the application is Microsoft Edge.  Up to a few months ago, when I cut and pasted the screen Outlook would preserve the formatting.  Now the formatting is not copied along with the text and the hyperlinks go away.  What could be doing this?  Maybe it isn't Outlook that is pasting it as Plain Text because I have been going over to IE and cutting and pasting from there and IE still preserves the formatting(but blows it up).

Comment: Which version of Outlook and Edge are you using? When pasted the content, please make sure it will keep the Source Format. You could check [this article](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/reset-or-keep-formatting-when-pasting-to-email) to verify the Outlook Cut and Pasted setting.

Comment: Outlook 2016 Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: Chrome works just the way EDGE used to - preserves the formatting exactly as it shows on the application

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem, I also use the same version of Edge and Outlook, the hyperlink keep format. After checking the outlook cut and pasted setting, whether it work well on your side? If still not working, try to use the outlook website, instead of outlook app, if it works well, perhaps the issue is related to the outlook app settings, you could try [resetting Outlook to defaults.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/reset-outlook-to-defaults/02a6341f-b7a9-4e69-a5dd-1a2d4e3b19a9).